# When constructing an array of default objects in MATLAB, why is the first element not constructed as instructed?

Tags: arrays, matlab, oop, constructor

That's a terrible title, but let me try to explain.  I have a class `test_class` that may be constructed one of two ways.  I can create a single object with default properties by calling `test_obj = test_class`, or I can create an array of objects with default properties by calling `test_obj_array = test_class([x,y])`.  Here's the full code:

```
classdef test_class

    properties
        A;
    end

    properties (Dependent = true)
        B;
    end

    methods

        function obj = test_class(S)

            if nargin == 0
                obj.A = 1;
            else
                x = size(S,1);
                y = size(S,2);
                obj(x,y) = test_class;
            end

        function B_value = get.B(obj)

            B_value = obj.A * 2;

        end

    end

end
```

Now, when I check the properties of these objects:

```
test_obj_array(1,1).A = []
test_obj_array(1,1).B = []

test_obj_array(1,2).A = 1
test_obj_array(1,2).B = 2
...
```

**Why is the first object in the array not constructed?**

Now, it's easy to fix by adding `test_obj_array(1,1) = test_class` or by modifying the properties later, but that's an easy thing to forget and a difficult thing to troubleshoot.

Note: this behavior is *not* seen if you pass an array of values to the constructor, as demonstrated in this [MATLAB documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/creating-object-arrays.html).

Comment: It's not constructed because you never instruct MATLAB to do so. By passing input arguments you bypass the no-argument constructor for the first object in your array. What do you intend `[x,y]` to be? The size of the output object array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what's going on under the hood here to make this behavior happen.  However, from the [MATLAB documentation on initializing object arrays](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/initialize-object-arrays.html), the syntax you can use to get the behavior you want is:

```
test_obj_array(x,y) = test_class;
```

This will call the default constructor properly.

Based on the documentation, which says

> When MATLAB calls a constructor with no arguments to initialize an object array, one of the following assignments occurs:
>
> - If property definitions specify default values, MATLAB assigns these
>     values.
> - If the constructor assigns values in the absence of input
>     arguments, MATLAB assigns these values.
> - If neither of the preceding
>     situations apply, MATLAB assigns the value of empty double (that is,
>     []) to the property.

In your case, the second bullet point ought to apply, but isn't for some reason.  I set some breakpoints inside the constructor, and when the object is initialized as an array from outside (i.e. the syntax I suggest above, that works), the default ctor is called for each non-explicitly-constructed object.  When initializing the array from inside the ctor, though, the default ctor isn't being called.  This is perhaps due to the expectation that each object will need to be explicitly initialized anyway (how array syntax is expected to work in the examples in the docs), so why do it twice, but... I agree with you, and I consider this a bug or at least a poor design choice by Mathworks.

---

On a side note, the logic you're using (that isn't working anyway) to determine the size of the array is messed up.  Passing `[3, 5]` gives you a `1x2` array as a result, because `size(S)` is 1x2, not 3x5...

Comment: The `size` call is possibly an issue but not for the reason stated. The second input to `size` [specifies the dimension](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/size.html#inputarg_dim), so it's going to return a scalar.

Comment: @excaza Yes, that's exactly what I'm saying. `size(S,1)` and `size(S,2)` give the size of the first and second dimensions of the input argument.  In this case, 1x2.  It seem what the OP actually wanted to do was to use S(1) and S(2) directly.  But this issue is orthogonal to the question of why some elements of the output are uninitialized.  If you try the syntax I suggest, you will see that the default constructor is appropriately called, unlike in the OP's code.

Comment: I see. The statement was unclear to me and seemed like you were talking about the return of `size`, not the constructor.

Comment: I think what's going on is that when a constructor is entered, `obj` is initialized to be a scalar (1 x 1) array of `test_class`, with the default properties from the `properties` section (defaulting to `[]` in this case). When the array is expanded with `obj(x,y) = test_class`, that first element is not re-initialized because it's not newly created by array expansion. If you pass a larger argument, say `a = test_class([1 2 3])`, you can see that the intermediate elements like `a(2)` are in fact initialized by the zero-arg constructor.

Comment: If you're just trying to initialize a uniform object array with the default values, you might want to do `obj = repmat(test_class, [x y])` or `obj = repmat(test_class, S)` inside the constructor instead.